# HTML text won't change when prompted by get function

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, bootstrap-4

in my game everytime you go through it should be updating the score within my get function. but i keep getting null property errors. some help would be greatly appreciated

i tried to invlude this const scoreElement = document.getElementById("scoreNums");

```
  scoreElement.innerText = score.correct + "/" + score.total;
```

inside my get function to change the text within each run through

here is my server side JS

```
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const port = 3042;
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


let score = 0;
let correct = 0;
//const scoreElement = document.getElementById("scoreNumbers");

// Increment score and update score element whenever a win occurs

//scoreElement.innerText = correct + "/" + score;



const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
};

server.use(allowCrossDomain);

server.post("/myPost", function (req, res) {
 score += req.body.score;
 correct += req.body.correct;
 //scoreElement.innerText = correct + "/" + score;
 let obj = {correct: correct, score: score};

 return res.status(201).send(obj);
});

server.get("/myGet", function (req, res) {
  const score = { correct: correct, score: score};

  return res.status(200).send(score);
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port 3042");
});
```

```js
/**
 * This is the javascript file for the mi'kmaq game. It adds all of the function
 * to make the game playable
 * 
 * @Authors Lucas: Displaying elements of the page after user input
 *          Aidan: Drag and Drop proccess
 *          Sahildeep: helping with Drag and Drop proccess and also dealing with the audio and random word
 *          Kunal: helped Sahildeep with checking if the answer is right or wrong
 * 
 */


//@author Sahildeep Singh
//array containing the audio files to be played
const audiosAry = ['aqq.wav', 'eliey.wav', 'kesalk.wav', 'kil.wav', 'ltu.wav', 'mijisi.wav', 'nin.wav', 'teluisi.wav', 'wiktm.wav'];
//array containg the pictures to be displayed as possible answers
const picsAry = ['aqqText.jpg', 'elieyText.jpg', 'kesalkText.jpg', 'kilText.jpg', 'ltuText.jpg', 'mijisiText.jpg', 'ninText.jpg', 'teluisiText.jpg', 'wiktmText.jpg'];
//variable holding a random index to choose the image and audio file to be played during the game(right answer)
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * audiosAry.length);
//variable holding the right answer 
const rightAnswer = picsAry[randomIndex];
// variable holding the server url
const SERVER_URL = "http://ugdev.cs.smu.ca:3042";
//variable holding the element with the score 



/**
 * @Author Sahildeep Singh
 * 
 * plays the audio that correlates to the word chosen in the showTextimg() function
 * 
 */

function playAudio() {
  const audio = new Audio("audios/" + audiosAry[randomIndex]);
  audio.play();
}

/**
 * @Author Sahildeep Singh
 * 
 * picks a random word from the array of mi'kmaq words and presents it to the user
 * 
 */

function showTextImg() {
  const audioPic = new String("images/" + picsAry[randomIndex]);
  document.getElementById("thisWord").src = audioPic;
}

/**
 * @Author Aidan Shand
 * 
 * allows the bear image to be dropped in the dropzones
 * 
 * @param {*} ev bear image that is in the drag event
 */
function allowDrop(event, image) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#ninText.jpg").show();
  $("#teluisiText.jpg").show();
  $("#wiktmText.jpg").show();
  $("#mijisiText.jpg").show();
  $("#ltuText.jpg").show();
  $("#kilText.jpg").show();
  $("#kesalkText.jpg").show();
  $("#elieyText.jpg").show();
  $("#aqqText.jpg").show();
  $("#" + image).hide();



}

/**
 * @Author Aidan Shand
 * 
 * starts the drag proccess for the bear image
 * 
 * @param {*} ev bear image that is in the drag event
 */
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}


/**
 * @Author Sahildeep Singh(finished), Aidan Shand(started)
 * 
 * allows the bear image to be dropped on the choices for answers and appends the bear image to the drop target
 * 
 * @param {*} ev bear image that is in the drag event
 * @param {*} clicked_id id of the image that was dropped on 
 */

function drop(ev, clicked_id) {
  const element = document.getElementById("drag2");
  element.draggable = false;
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var el = ev.target;
  if (!el.classList.contains('dropzone')) {
    el = ev.target.parentNode;
    ev.target.remove();
  }
  el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

  checkRightOrWrong(clicked_id);

}

/**
 * @Author Sahildeep Singh, Kunal Singla 
 * 
 * checks if the user has chosen the right answer for the drop and displays win and loss screen
 * 
 * @param {*} clicked_id id of the image that was dropped on
 */
function checkRightOrWrong(clicked_id) {
  if (clicked_id == rightAnswer) {
    displayWin();

  } else {
    displayLoss();

  }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * @Author Lucas
 * 
 * Resets the game by refreshing the clients screen
 * 
 */
function displayStart() {
  window.location.reload();
  get();
}

/**
 * @Author Lucas
 * 
 * Displays the loss screen with flowers 
 * 
 */
function displayLoss() {
  toggleImage("topSun");
  toggleImage("bottomSun");
  toggleImage("lossText");

  //change top to reset option
  toggleImage("volume");
  toggleImage("thisWord");
  toggleImage("resetButton");
  let obj = {
    correct: 0,
    score: 1
  };
  $.post(SERVER_URL + "/myPost", obj, successFn).fail(errorFn);
}

function displayWin() {
  toggleImage("topStar");
  toggleImage("bottomStar");
  toggleImage("successText");
  //toggleImage("drag2");


  //change top to reset option
  toggleImage("volume");
  toggleImage("thisWord");
  toggleImage("resetButton");
  let obj = {
    correct: 1,
    score: 1
  }
  $.post(SERVER_URL + "/myPost", obj, successFn).fail(errorFn);
}

/**
 * @Author Aidan created the function, and further optimized after Lucas's adjustments
 * @Author Lucas fixed the display styles
 * 
 * Function to hide and display an image on the grid
 * 
 * @param {*} imageId the id of the image to be hidden or shown
 */
function toggleImage(imageId) {
  var image = document.getElementById(imageId);
  if (image.style.display === 'none') {
    image.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    image.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function get() {
  $.get(SERVER_URL + "/myGet", function(data) {
    // parse the JSON response
    const score = JSON.parse(data);

    // update the UI with the new score data
    const scoreElement = document.getElementById("scoreNums");

    scoreElement.innerText = score.correct + "/" + score.total;
  }).fail(function(error) {
    console.log("Error occurred while fetching data: " + error.statusText);
  });
}

function successFn(returnedData) {
  console.log(returnedData);
}

/*
  The purpose of this function is to log the error.
  
  err - the error object returned by the server
  
  Author: Terry Goldsmith
*/
function errorFn(err) {
  console.log(err.responseText);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--

This file is the web page for the mi'kmaq game

@Authors: Lucas layout of the bootstrap grid and the images, commenting
          Aidan
          Sahlideep
          Kunal
-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Link to bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- link to jQuery-->
  <script src="JS/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <!-- link to JS file-->
  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/Eserver.js"></script>

  <title>Project Part 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Bootstrap grid @Authors Lucas, Adian, Sahildeep -->
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <!-- Spacing for formatting  -->
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>

      <!-- Volume and word -->
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="images/vol.jpg" onclick="playAudio();" onload="showTextImg()" id="volume" />
      </div>
      <div id="resetButton" style="display: none" onclick="displayStart()">
        <h1><strong>si'owas'si?</strong></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2"><img src="" id="thisWord" /></div>

      <!-- Display the score at the start of the game -->
      <div class="col-2" id="scoreWords">
        <strong>Click Your Score: </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="scoreNums">0/0</div>
    </div>

    <!-- First row of the grid, including the top flower and top star -->
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <!-- Star image -->
      <div class="col" id="sideColumn">
        <img src="images/star.jpg" id="topStar" style="display: none" />
      </div>

      <!-- Top 3 images -->
      <div class="col dropzone" id="wiktmText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'wiktmText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/wiktm.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="col dropzone" id="teluisiText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'teluisiText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/teluisi.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="col dropzone" id="ninText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'ninText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/nin.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>

      <!-- flower image -->
      <div class="col" id="sideColumn">
        <img src="images/sun.jpg" id="topSun" style="display: none" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second row of grid, including fail message and success message / bear -->
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <!-- Location of the bear -->
      <div class="col" id="sideColumn">
        <img src="images/bear.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" />
        <img src="images/successText.jpg" id="successText" style="display: none" />
      </div>

      <!-- Second row of 3 images -->
      <div class="col dropzone" id="mijisiText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'mijisiText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/mijisi.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="col dropzone" id="ltuText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'ltuText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/ltu.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="col dropzone" id="kilText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'kilText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/kil.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>

      <!-- Text for loss screen -->
      <div class="col" id="sideColumn">
        <img src="images/oopsText.jpg" id="lossText" style="display: none" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Third row of grid including the bottom star and bottom flower -->
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col" id="sideColumn">
        <img src="images/star.jpg" id="bottomStar" style="display: none" s />
      </div>

      <!-- Bottom 3 images-->
      <div class="col dropzone" id="kesalkText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'kesalkText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/kesalk.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="col dropzone" id="elieyText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'elieyText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/eliey.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="col dropzone" id="aqqText.jpg" ondrop="drop(event, this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event,'aqqText.jpg')">
        <img src="images/aqq.jpg" draggable="false" />
      </div>

      <!-- Bottom flower image -->
      <div class="col" id="sideColumn">
        <img src="images/sun.jpg" id="bottomSun" style="display: none" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] with relevant description of how to trigger the issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact issue.but you declare the score  variable Twice in your code globally and once in side server.get function, and since it is defined inside the function, it is shadowing the global variable.